# Regular expression not working as a HTML5 pattern validator

Tags: javascript, regex, html, validation

I'm trying to validate if a URL ends with `.png`:

```
/.[a-zA-z]\.(png)$/i
```

However, it doesn't seem to be working when using it as a value for a `pattern` attribute, but everything seems to be fine [here (regex101.com)](https://regex101.com/r/SkA8DH/1/).

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="url" pattern="/.[a-zA-z]\.(png)$/i" value="" required >
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

A test string to validate:

```
http://imgur.com/foo.png
```

I want to match `o.png` or everything after the last forward slash and ends with a `.png`

Comment: You don't need `g` flag for "ends with".

Comment: `console.log(/\.png$/.test('adasdaads.png'))`

Comment: In what way not working?  It's letting things pass that shouldn't or stopping things that should pass?

Comment: If all you need is to check wither it ends with ".png" then all you need is `\.png$` -- the rest of the regex is unnecessary.

Comment: @DanielBeck My goal is to validate if its a url(type="url") and if it ends with a `.png`(pattern="...").

Comment: Many websites do optimization and don't use any extension to make dynamic images with adoptive sizes and compression. Dynamic generated image like [this one](http://www.reliablecounter.com/count.php?page=reliablecounter.comzdzd&digit=style/plain/1/&reloads=1) is still a png but don't have any extension. some url do but added a `.png?width=200`. and serve it as jpeg or webp (depending on accept header) I think you should accept any url, make a (head or normal) request and check if the content-type is image/png and possible abort the request

Comment: @Endless Nice 'gotcha'. Will sure keep this in mind

Comment: @Adam, “It's letting things pass that shouldn't” it is happening to me on my local software. I am using a code editor, actually the one of Dreamweaver, but also I am using Brackets. I cleared the history, the chachè, and failing. My pattern is `[A-Za-z]{2,30} ` and when a input characters like $%^@!2345, they are validated! why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to put your regex between forward slashes.

Right now your regex matches:

- any charcter `.`
- and upper or lowercase character [a-zA-Z]
- a dot `\.`
- dot png in a captured group `(\.png)`

So this would match an url with 2 characters and then .png.

You could use [`^.+\.png`](https://regex101.com/r/M1ALDx/1) to match any character one or more times `.+` and then match dot png at the end of the line `\.png$`.

You can extend the `.+` to match your criteria.

```html
<form action="#">
    <input type="text" pattern="^.+\.png$" value="" required >
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: don't work with dynamic generated images like this: `foo.png?size=400`

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input):

> **pattern**
>
> A regular expression that the control's value is checked against. The pattern must match the entire value, not just some subset. Use the title attribute to describe the pattern to help the user. This attribute applies when the value of the type attribute is text, search, tel, url, email, or password, otherwise it is ignored. The regular expression language is the same as JavaScript RegExp algorithm, with the 'u' parameter that makes it treat the pattern as a sequence of unicode code points. **The pattern is not surrounded by forward slashes.**

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="text" pattern=".[a-zA-z]\.(png)$" value="" required >
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it still doesn't seem to be working for me

Comment: @user3284463 Well, it works according to the regex you provided. If the regex is incorrect, then that's a different thing.

Comment: @Rusty, I am facing a similar issue. When I test  in online testers like rgexr.com, my patterns look to work fine but on my code editor, or in the Dreamweaver, don‘t work. Five years later, can you please tell me if you found the answer?